# Python convert a string to tuple

Tags: python

If I have data like this from a machine learning prediction:

`print(prediction)` is:

`('blood_pressure', '0.99999046')`

Then `print(type(prediction))` is:

`<class 'str'>`

How do I convert this to a tuple?

If i do `print(tuple(prediction))` this comes out like:

```
('(', "'", 'b', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'd', '_', 'p', 'r', 'e', 's', 's', 'u', 'r', 'e', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '0', '.', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '0', '4', '6', "'", ')')
```

Comment: Duplicate found by copying your questions title into google.

Comment: You can `eval` it. But more importantly, why is such a string being created in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the builtin `eval()` function.

```py
tuple_as_string = "('blood_pressure', '0.99999046')"
tuple_as_tuple = eval(tuple_as_string)
print(tuple_as_tuple)
print(type(tuple_as_tuple))
```

Comment: Thanks for this I have never heard of eval before, ill have to look into it...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use eval, as it is inherently unsecure this is also possible, even though not as elegant:

```
s = "('blood_pressure', '0.99999046')"
s.replace("(","").replace(")","").replace("'","").split(",")
['blood_pressure', ' 0.99999046']
```

Comment: I know this is an old comment, but just as a shortcut, you could use `s.strip("()'")` instead of the multiple calls to `replace`.